# How to create a random matches in a league database with the ID of the clubs?

Tags: php, mysql

I work on a project about chess league. I have a table consists of ( round_id, home_club, away_club, home_results, away_results ). I want to generate a random matches for 18 rounds ( the league consists of 10 clubs) so that in home_club and away_club we have a club_id from another table but not repeated in each round.

Comment: Sounds like a great project.  Keep us informed of the progress you make.

Answer (score 0):

Let, there is a table `clubs` in your database with `ID` column, that contains identificators (from 1 to 10 for example). Then use following:

```
SELECT home.ID, away.ID
FROM clubs home, clubs away
WHERE home.ID <> away.ID
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 18;
```

The `SELECT home.ID, away.ID FROM clubs home, clubs away` creates all combinations of identificators. The `WHERE` clause prevents equality of `home.ID` and `away.ID` values in the result. The `ORDER BY RAND()` returns rows in random order. Finally, we get first 18 rows only.
Thus, the 18 random combinations identificators of clubs will be returned. The query result is able to be [inserted](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) into `home_club` and `away_club` columns of your tournament table.